# Is it possible to create NSFetchedResultsController to fetch all entities with distinct values for specific property?

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Suppose I have `Person` entity with properties: `id, name, age`:

And I have following records:

```
101, Katherine, 23
102, Madelaine, 23
103, Katherine, 27
104, Vicky, 18
105, Kirsten, 45
106, Vicky, 12
```

And I need all records sorted by age, without duplicating name.

The output should be:

```
105, Kirsten, 45
103, Katherine, 27
102, Madelaine, 23
104, Vicky, 18
```

This is how I create NSFRC:

```
    let context = NSManagedObjectContext.mr_default()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Person>(entityName: "Person")
    let ageDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "age", ascending: false)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [ageDescriptor]

    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
```

**How to apply rule to fetch all persons and only one (oldest) person with the same name?**

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Do you need to search the person based on a string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property `returnsDistinctResults` and `propertiesToFetch`in NSFetchrequest to return only distinct results of a fetch request. In your case the propertiesToFetch will be the name of the entity.

You can find more info here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest

Just as example code. (I am doing it off top of my head so may not be 100% accurate with exact syntax):

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Person", in: context)

let entityProperties = entity.propertiesByName
let namePropertyDescription = entityProperties["name"]

fetchrequest.propertiesToFetch = [namePropertyDescription]
fetchrequest.returnsDistinctResults = true
```

Comment: name of the entity may be "propertyToFetch"? Really? Unbelieveable:)

Comment: What I meant was you would assign the name field of your entiry to the 'propertiesToFetch'  of NSFetchRequest

Comment: Please, provide example... I am not sure If I understand tou